# Removing too specific tags like crowd-control

Tags: discussion, tags

I notice that there are very specific tags like 'crowd control' which is not an area of Sci-Fi or Fantasy nor is it relevant to any particular work. Do we need tags like this?

What is the policy on creating new tags/removing unused and old tags?

Answer (score 3):

If you notice an ultraspecific tag, you can remove it or replace it by a more general tag. Ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) or on [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you aren't sure.

Comment: what should you do if you find a tag that should be removed [pendragon](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/pendragon/info), but you don't have enough rep to do it yourself?

Comment: @numaroth If a tag is only used on a small number of questions, you can edit those questions to remove it (that's the normal way to remove a tag anyway: it goes away if no more questions use it). Unless it's obvious, ask for advice in chat or on meta before unilaterally removing a tag. If a tag is used on more than a handful of questions, removing it warrants a meta discussion.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the quick response.